How to get commits from the original repository of my forked repository?
Let's say there is a very well-known open source library called famous and I've forked it into my github to make adjustment for my own interest. I've made some commits and pushed it to my remote github repository. However, I want to update my famous' repo with its original repository's commits, and will keep doing this process continuously as well, such as writing my own code and get some updates from its original source and repeat it... If there's a conflict in merging from the kind of two branches, choose manually...
Does this kind of logic could work in github?

Maybe you are looking for looking for git rebase origin/main and git log combination?
